# Can't get accelerator key to work with WPF radio button

Tags: wpf

I am trying to assign a shortcut to a WPF radio button which is inside a grid which is inside a tab item. I tried simply using the underline character as shown which marks the label with an underline on the letter "F" but when sending the keys "Alt+f" it simply will not select the radio button.

```
    <RadioButton Name="DesktopRadioButtonFlags" Content="_Flags" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
   Margin="39,39,0,0" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Top" FlowDirection="RightToLeft"/>
```

Comment: Thanks but I still have an issue. Basically I have found that when hosting a WPF user control in a WinForm project, and then adding a WPF radio button to the user control with a shortcut key, the shortcut key is ignored? And the input bindings. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use input bindings

xaml

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Alt" Key="F" Command="{Binding CheckRadioButton1Command}"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
<Grid>
    <RadioButton Content="_Flags" IsChecked="{Binding IsRadioChecked}"/>
</Grid>
```

viewmodel

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isRadioChecked;
    public bool IsRadioChecked
    {
        get => _isRadioChecked;
        set
        {
            if (_isRadioChecked == value)
                return;

            _isRadioChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsRadioChecked));
        }
    }

    private ICommand _checkRadioButton1Command;
    public ICommand CheckRadioButton1Command => _checkRadioButton1Command ?? (_checkRadioButton1Command = new ActionCommand(CheckRadioButton1));

    private void CheckRadioButton1()
    {
        IsRadioChecked = true;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

control or windows code to set ViewModel as DataContext (you should pass your initial data to windows or control constructor)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MyViewModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the type or namespace "ActionCommand" could not be found, also see my comment above regarding hosting WPF UserControl in Windows form project. Thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: Nuget Package Microsoft.Xaml.Behavior.Wpf or any different ICommand implemetation from your favorite MVVM framework. You could place InputBindings in your WPF control, but it will work when control has focus.

Comment: Thanks so I have added the package but still can't get it to work. My XAML is as you have it with the key bindings but not quite sure how I add the INotifyPropertyChangedInterface viewmodel. Presently it is added as a class within the WPF user control source code file. Sorry I'm fairly new to WPF so not quite getting the binding syntax.

Comment: it's not such a hard think, but I corrected my answer and added implementation for INotifyPropertyChanged and also setting DataContext

Comment: That did it thank you Lana, really appreciate your help.