# Problem with WPF radio button shortcut key when hosting WPF UserControl in WinForm project

Tags: wpf

I have found that when hosting a WPF UserControl, in a Windows Form project, and then adding a WPF radio button with a shortcut key to the user control as shown below the shortcut key is ignored. That is if I send keys "Alt+f" when the WPF user control has focus then nothing happens. Is there a way to remedy this?

```
   <Grid>
    <RadioButton Content="_Flags"/>
   </Grid>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't get accelerator key to work with WPF radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65643932/cant-get-accelerator-key-to-work-with-wpf-radio-button)

Comment: Yes thank you it does answer the question and solves the issue, many thanks.